# Choropleth map not filled in/ hover isn't working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, choropleth

I created a small excel file listing the confirmed cases, deaths, and recovered cases of the Coronavirus here in the U.S, but I can't seem to get the choropleth map working.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
```

```
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

col_Names=["State", "Country", "Time Discovered", "Confirmed",  "Deaths","Recovered"]

df = pd.read_csv("coronavirusUS.csv", names=col_Names)
data = dict(type='choropleth',
           colorscale= 'magma',
           locations = df['State'],
           locationmode= 'USA-states', 
           z = df['Confirmed'],
           text = df['Confirmed'],
            marker = dict(line=dict(color='rgb(255, 255, 255)', width=2)),
           colorbar = {'title':'Coronavirus in the U.S'})


layout = dict(title = 'Coronavirus in the US',
             geo= dict(scope = 'usa',
                      showlakes = True,
                      lakecolor = 'rgb(85, 173, 240)'))


choromap = go.Figure(data = [data], layout = layout)
iplot(choromap)
```

And then my map comes out looking like this:
[empty map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hZYD.png)
As you can see, the colorbar is accurate, but the map itself is blank. Except for the lakes.

Here's the .csv file I'm referring to.
[data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypoow.png)

I'm using jupyter notebook.

I've tried switching from a .xls to .csv, but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance.